# Different size of font in one line of code

Tags: html, css

I have a hard time explaining the problem, but I have added a screenshot. This problem is NOT in any postings on the Blog.

[image: Size difference in letters "a" "e" "o" compared to others]

There are at the moment when I realized the problem only 7 Postings and this is posting Number 5. So it is not the first, nor the last nor ever X Post (Maybe I should create 10 to see if it comes up again?).

I have triple checked the HTML Code in the posting itself, in the shown source code and the controlling css via "Inspect Element" Everything is clean, there are no dozens of `<span>` or whatnot tags that might mess up the display of this particular posting.

I have removed all striketrough CSS Code, as from what I know it means that it isn't active and to be ignored anyway:

```
.coller .out-thumb .entry-excerpt {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #3e3e3e;
    padding-left: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 5px;}

.grid .out-thumb .entry-excerpt {
    font-weight: 400;}

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    border: 0;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    word-wrap: break-word;}
```

Do you guys have ANY idea what could cause this? I have no idea how often I have checked the Code now, but I really can't find anything.

Comment: Can you share a link with the actual problem?

Comment: Verify that those are actually `'o'` (0x006F), `'e'` (0x0065), and `'a'` (0x0061) characters, and not say `'ｏ'` (0xFF4F), `'ｅ'` (0xFF45), and `'ａ'` (0xFF41).

Comment: To confirm @zzzzBov thought you can check them [here](http://www.mauvecloud.net/charsets/CharCodeFinder.html)

Comment: More like accidentally I have changed the Zoom on the Page, still seaching for the Problem and ... Well, Everything was suddenly at 110% the same and proper. I have also tried this Charakter Code Finder for the Circled Letters: о е а, Hexadecimal Character Codes: `0x43e, 0x435, 0x430` .. All in all it seems to be related to the displayed size of the Letters, rather than a Code issue. 12pt / 16px makes no difference ... Never ever had I had this issue before.... And URL to Page: `http://www.dirksproduktbewertungen.com/`

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the text uses characters that are similar to `a`, `e`, and `o`, but are not the normal Latin `a`, `e`, and `o` characters. Instead they're in the Cyrillic range.

The page is using the Lato `font-family`, and the version of that `font-family` appears to be missing the 'а' (`&#x430;`), 'е' (`&#x435;`), and 'о' (`&#x43E;`) characters. I'm not sure if they're supported by the extended Latin version of Lato.

Regardless, because the loaded version of Lato doesn't include glyphs for those characters, the browser falls back to the next font-family, which is set to `sans-serif`, which is why those glyphs appear at the wrong size.

One solution might be to replace the characters used with regular Latin characters, however if you were relying on someone else for content entry, it's likely that the issue will come back when they type those characters from their keyboard.

If the characters are available in the extended Latin version of Lato, making sure you load the more inclusive font should fix the issue.

If Lato doesn't provide glyphs for those characters, you may need to create a custom font that contains the necessary characters to use as a fallback. Creating a custom font is far too broad for this specific question, so I will leave it as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Should be pretty simple to use JS to replace the characters. Much easier than creating a new custom font.

Comment: I had indeed someone write the first seven postings before I decided to do it better myself... I thought it might be better to have them written, or mainly rewritten properly, than to post it myself, but I found that I get a quality back that was on par with mine or worst. --- How can I solve the Problem with this Post now? Either JS or other way? I have added the code to Dreamweaver Design Windows and copied from the Code Window and Put it back to the Code of the Page, but Problem still persists.. getting nuts on this... but still trying ;)

Comment: Deleted my old Comment to redo it. Was not as easy as it seemed. Got tired or searching for 'wrong' Letter, so tried a mind Numbing Search and Replace for the whole Alphabet. That didn't work. In the end I found that I could just put everything to Dreamweaver -> Page Properties -> Title/Encoding -> Westeuropean. Now I got Text like this `Tr&#1086;tz d&#1077;r B&#1110;ld&#1077;r` and I could Fix two postings in no time! .... At Last!

Comment: Your page is still not "clean". For instance the title Meine Erfahrungen mit еіnеm Quаdrосорtеr" still contains several Russian letters. (You can see this by the generated link URL, which contains only ASCII letters and is missing the offending ones: "meine-erfahrungen-mit-nm-qudrtr/").

Comment: Oh f***, sure, I had only checked the Content, not the titles. THANKS @Mr-Lister, I have completely forgotten to check that too, I will fix it as soon as possible!